# HTML / CSS Layout Issue

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm looking at a simple web page layout but I want to fix the 3 centred columns to an absolute maximum height.

I've created this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pv7uY/), which is missing the images, but as you can see the first column is longer than the others as there more text in it.

This appears to be the css that is being used, but I'm not sure what to change.

```
.home_section_left{
width:270px;
height:auto;
float:left;
margin:0 14px 0 14px;
padding:0 10px 20px 10px;
background:url(images/home_block_bg.gif) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

How do I fix the length of the columns regardless of the length of data/text entered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `max-height` and `overflow: auto;` to the tags you want to limit the height like this:

```
.home_section_left {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This will limit the div height and apply scrollbars to it when necessary

Comment: Thanks and If I don't want scroll bars ? Just limit the height and truncate any extra text ?

Comment: you can set `overflow` to `hidden`, that will remove all scrollbars

Comment: The left column is 500px high on my computer, so I think you'll need at least that if you want them all to be the same. Or 42em if you want to be independent of font size.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help as your needs,

```
.home_section_left 
{
width: 270px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
margin: 0 14px 0 14px;
padding: 0 10px 20px 10px;
overflow: hidden;
background: url(images/home_block_bg.gif) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```